# SimpleDateFormat provide wrong year

Tags: android, kotlin, simpledateformat, date-formatting, android-date

According to picture below, when I use `item.takendate` to `SimpleDateFormat`

I got **"January 2016"** instead of **"January 2017"**

what happen here? please advice.

[image]

**Edit**

However, when I use cdate parse back to Date it value is changed from 1st January to 2nd January

[image]

Comment: It looks like `2017` in your image.

Comment: Looks like your camera is saving file with wrong date, so is the image's metadata corrupted.

Comment: @Heisen-Berg it's 2017, but when I use SimpleDateFormat to format date result is 2016

Comment: @Hubertoss is it related to camera file saving ??

Comment: Well, I spotted that the picture is saved with date of 2017/01/01 in the name, if they are saved externally then I would check it. Otherwise, if you save them yourself then it is you should change "YYYY" to "yyyy". YYYY stands for WEEK_OF_YEAR in Java 8 and is synchronized with the week numbers.

Comment: @Hubertoss all this data fetch from system only no update, thank you anyway

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy" date format to java.sql.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43933597/eee-mmm-dd-hhmmss-zzz-yyyy-date-format-to-java-sql-date)

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When using `SimpleDateFormat`, `YYYY` and `yyyy` have different meanings! You almost certainly want to use `yyyy` (actual year) instead of `YYYY` (week year).

Comment: Solved, thank you, I will accept answer when it allow.

Comment: A bit of explanation: the first of january 2017 may have week number 52 of "week" year 2016; and the following Monday (generally) then is week 1 of (week and calendar) year 2017.