# Spring Boot Date conversion from Form

Tags: java, date, localdate

I'm having a few issues with getting a date from a controller because I don't understand what's the right format for it to work.

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/findFlights", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String findFlights(@RequestParam("from") String from, @RequestParam("to") String to,
            @RequestParam("departureDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "YYYY-MM-DD") LocalDate departureDate, Model model) {}
```

**Form:**

```
<form th:action="@{/findFlights}" method="POST">
        From:<input type="text" name="from" required/>
        To:<input type="text" name="to" required/>
        Departure Date:<input type="date" name="departureDate"  required />
        <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

When I submit the form it always gives me an error no matter what the format of the date is :( Here is the error:

> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'java.time.LocalDate'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
>   [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam
>   @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat
>   java.time.LocalDate] for value '2018-11-05'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value
>   [2018-11-05]

If I specify the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation I thought that the conversion would be done automatically.

Comment: Related (but not the same): [“EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy” date format to java.sql.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43933597/eee-mmm-dd-hhmmss-zzz-yyyy-date-format-to-java-sql-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `YYYY-MM-DD` pattern `Y` is a week year and `D` is day in a year as per [SimpleDateFormat javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). For standard dates the pattern should be `yyyy-MM-dd`:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

or if you want to use `DateTimeFormat.ISO` enum:

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
```

Comment: Thanks! It Works now!