# How to get data between two dates REST Spring

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

My Controller Mapping

```
@GetMapping("/fetch/{one_date}/{two_date}")
public List<CourierInfo> getData_between(@PathVariable(value = "one_date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyyMMdd") LocalDateTime fromDate, @PathVariable(value = "two_date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyyMMdd") LocalDateTime toDate) {
    return bookRepository.getData_between(fromDate, toDate);
}
```

My Custom Query

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value="select c.cons_no, c.pick_date, from CourierInfo c where c.pick_date between :startDate and :endDate")
```

List getData_between(@Param("startDate") LocalDateTime date, @Param("endDate") LocalDateTime date2);

I am passing

```
http://localhost:8080/book_api/fetch/2020-01-20/2020-01-20
```

Here I am trying to fetch data between two dates.
I am getting this error

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDateTime] for value '"2020-01-20"'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value ["2020-01-20"]
```

Comment: 20200120 is a string you need a date

Comment: tried 2020-01-20. not working

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164864/how-to-accept-date-params-in-a-get-request-to-spring-mvc-controller

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to accept Date params in a GET request to Spring MVC Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164864/how-to-accept-date-params-in-a-get-request-to-spring-mvc-controller)

Answer (score 1):

First of all stop using `java.util.Date` and start using `LocalDate` from java-8 date time API, you can parse the input date string into `LocalDate` using `DateTimeFormatter`

```
@GetMapping("/fetch/{one_date}/{two_date}")
public List<CourierInfo> getData_between(@PathVariable(value = "one_date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDate fromDate, @PathVariable(value = "two_date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDate toDate) {
    return bookRepository.getData_between(fromDate, toDate);
}
```

And in the repository

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value="select c.cons_no, c.pick_date, from CourierInfo c where c.pick_date between :startDate and :endDate")
List<CourierInfo> getData_between(@Param("startDate") LocalDate date, @Param("endDate") LocalDate date2);
```

Comment: http://localhost:8080/book_api/fetch/2020-01-20/2020-01-23    passed this still error

Comment: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime';   this is error I am getting

Comment: can you update your post with request and stack trace @MayankS.Gupta

Comment: Notice that the pattern `yyyyMMdd` accepts `20200120`, not `2020-01-20`. I'd use `@DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE)` for the sake of standards.

Comment: Since you have only date just use `LocalDate` and make sure the input request date format should match `DateTimeFormatter` @MayankS.Gupta, try the updated code

Comment: you are not at all trying anything, read my comment first @MayankS.Gupta the input date string should match the pattern in `DateTimeFormatter` annotation

Answer (score 0):

Check this topic :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53188501/4135813

The problem is related to missing converter in your endpoint configuration

Comment: Just specify @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyyMMdd") before the parameter  toDate in the controller method